# Redirecting to a Users Home Page with React upon Login

Tags: reactjs

I am building my first react app,

Currently I am trying to redirect a user to their home page after putting in their login credentials.

My click handler is redirecting them back to the root page, but that doesn't set up a good user experience. I want them to render their show page.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const user = Object.assign({}, this.state);
  this.props.form(user)
    .then(
      () => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    );
}
```

I changed the .push to,

```
this.props.history.push(`/api/users/${user.id}`)
```

User in this case is routing to /api/users/undefined..

The login works, because it does log a user in and renders the root afterward.

I also have a working user show page that shows the users profile.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that `this.state` is not empty since it is the only source of data for the `user` variable. It is possible that `handleSubmit` is invoked before `setState` is finished.

Comment: Also, can you add the code where you logged the user and where `handleSubmit` is called.

Comment: Seems like your user doesn't have an ID (which is to be expected, since you're only just doing the login call there, I suppose).

Does your login-call return anything? If it does, you can use that data in your `then` callback.
If not, you'll have to fetch the user's data from somewhere by, for example, doing a `/me` api-call after logging the user in.